# Can we make custom horizontal NumberPicker in our own without library?

Tags: android, android-number-picker

```
    <NumberPicker
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Can we make custom numberpicker using the NumberPicker and adding some Drawable ?
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4DZL.png)

Comment: find any library and modify that lib as you want

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/numberpicker/) is a link with a quite detailed tutorial about what you can change in the style of the numberpicker without using a library. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I want Horizontal Number Picker